# How do I add a categorical legend to a double line graph in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, linegraph

Here is my [Current View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BV0xq.png)

I'm wanting to add a legend to distinguish between members(yellow line)  and casual riders (blue line) so viewers can see which line is which.

Seems like this should be simple, but I feel like I've tried everything.  The closest I've come is by getting a legend to pop up by dragging measure values over to the color, but then it changes my colors that I have already established and syncs both lines as the same color or gradient of colors.  All I need is a legend detailing which line is which.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of individually changing each line's color, place Measure Names in the Color shelf of All marks card. This should make the legend appear on the right.

[image]